# modifying colorbar in matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to save an image I generated using seaborn. The image is 4x4 confusion matrix ('confmat' np.array). I learned that when I save the image in vector format, certain viewers have issues resulting in white lines on colorbar, quoting from matplotlib reference:

> It is known that some vector graphics viewer (svg and pdf) renders
> white gaps between segments of the colorbar. This is due to bugs in
> the viewers not matplotlib. As a workaround the colorbar can be
> rendered with overlapping segments:
>
> cbar = colorbar()
>
> cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
>
> draw()

However, I have trouble doing what is suggested.

Here is what I did:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap=plt.cm.Blues

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
ax = sns.heatmap(confmat, annot=True, cmap=cmap)
ax.set_title('title')
ax.tick_params(
    axis='both',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off',  # labels along the bottom edge are off
    labelleft='off',
    right='off')

fig.savefig('confusion_matrix.svg', format='svg')
```

I tried to get colorbar using

```
cbar = ax.colorbar()
```

But get an error AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'.

I searched for solution and found a few questions here that suggest using plt.imshow() to get the colorbar object, but I'm completely confused about what I'm doing by now.
Can someone suggest, and if possible, explain why, the solution for implementing what matplotlib documentation has offered for colorbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(10, 10)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(x)
cbar_ax = f.axes[-1]
cbar_solids = cbar_ax.collections[0]
cbar_solids.set_edgecolor("face")
f.savefig("heatmap.svg")
```

Comment: Much better solution, I couldn't work out how to get the colorbar handle from the figure. Assumed there would be a colorbar object on the second axis but in `matplotlib` a colorbar seems to be stored as type `QuadMesh`, which is a little confusing.

Comment: I had to use `cbar_solids.set_alpha(None)` to remove the stripes. `set_edgecolor('face')` wasn't needed and didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a `colorbar` with `cb.solid.set_edgecolor("face")` as suggested in the matplotlib docs appears to be a bit of a hack to ensure there are no white lines between elements on the colorbar. I think seaborn is designed assuming you should be able to do everything you need by passing kwargs (cbar_kws in heatmap). For example, you can pass `cb_kwargs` to the `sns.heatmap` function `cbar_kws={"drawedges": "False"}` but unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem.

As the `Seaborn` `Heatmap` only returns an axis handle on which the `heatplot` and the `colorbar` are plotted, you don't have direct access to the mappable object, `cbar` in the source code. As a result you can't apply this hack.

One solution is to just plot this using `pcolormesh` and `colorbar`. I think seaborn actually redefines matplotlib styles so should look the same,

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap=plt.cm.Blues

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
confmat = np.random.rand(4, 4)

cb = ax.pcolormesh(confmat, cmap=cmap)

ax.set_title('title')
ax.tick_params(
    axis='both',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off',  # labels along the bottom edge are off
    labelleft='off',
    right='off')

cbar = plt.colorbar(cb)
cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
plt.draw()

fig.savefig('confusion_matrix.svg', format='svg')
```

The result for me looks to be rid of the white lines when you zoom in.